# mariabackup, can i update full back up

Tags: mariadb

I have taken a full backup. Next week I take an incremental backup. Can I use the `prepare` statement to sync the full backup with the incremental backup? So, next time I can use the full backup as base dir for incremental backup. Hence avoiding a new incremental folder every week.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can use the incremental backup to prepare the full backup. This will then bring the full backup in sync with the `to_lsn` line in `xtrabackup_checkpoints` file located in your incremental backup directory. This line should have the same value as the one in your full backup directory after `--prepare` command. Once you confirm you can then delete the contents of that incremental directory for reuse.